# getting currently installed package name (via xposed)

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, xposed

I'm trying to build a module using xposed that will make a sort of blacklist of package names that will be blocked for installation through all options (google play, adb, package installer)
Apparently the most efficient way is to connect to class android.content.pm.packageinstaller

```
public void handleLoadPackage(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.google.android.packageinstaller"))
        return;

    hookPackageNameClass(lpparam);
}

private void hookPackageNameClass(XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) {
    Class <?> RecentsviewView = XposedHelpers.findClass("android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.SessionParams", lpparam.classLoader);
    findAndHookMethod(RecentsviewView, "setAppPackageName", String.class, new XC_MethodHook() {

        protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            super.afterHookedMethod(param);

            XposedBridge.log("----1111 Obj hook----:  " + param.thisObject);
            XposedBridge.log("----1111 Method hook----:  " + param.method);
            XposedBridge.log("----1111 Args hook----:  " + param.args);
            XposedBridge.log("----1111 result hook----:  " + param.getResult().toString());
        }
    });
}
```

You're right,
The question is flawed
I'm trying to connect to this function as you can see in the code to try to take the current package name sent for installation (and then compare it with some list and block the installation process if necessary...)
But the value I get from param.getResult is null or some random number....
I'm pretty desperate, can't find another function to hook into to get the package name in the current install process.

Comment: `setAppPackageName` is a method that return `void` so it is expected that `param.getResult()` returns null. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams#setAppPackageName(java.lang.String) In your search for hookable functions have you checked AOSP source code like [PackageManager.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.java)? IMHO I would use `frida-trace` to quick check if a method is called and with what arguments.

Comment: As far as I understand, the PackageManager.class class is only to receive information about applications that are already installed on the device and not about what happens during the actual installation process (I performed tests on this class while the package installer is performing an installation and it seems that it does not use the aforementioned class at all).
I found this function `public String getAppPackageName()` 
which seems to be the best fit, but it also returns nothing.

Comment: To me this class like the container class you use to send installation requests via IPC from the app who wants to perform an installation to the package installer service. I don't know how Android IPC serialization works internally but if it doesn't use getter/setter methods then the method `setAppPackageName` is only called in the app that triggers the installation. Thus it may seem to you that it is never called (but it is called just in a different process). The whole IPC stuff doesn't make it easy to understand where what happens. Or the method is not called because it is optional.